# Is there a way to assign numbers to several variables in the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a school project relating to calendars. I want to assign the input, i.e the name of a month, to a number. January to 1, February to 2, etc. For the time being, I've just used

```
if month == ('JANUARY'):
    month = 1
if month == ('FEBRUARY'):
    month = 2
```

and so on, but doing that with every month is ugly and takes up a lot of space. Is there a way to have all of the months in one line and assign the selected month its corresponding number?

Comment: Looks like you can use a dictionary.. or use `calendar` module

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one:

```
month = ['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', ...].index(month) + 1
```

[index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns the position of an element into a list, starting at 0.

Comment: You can enclose the line with try: / except ValueError: to manage errors

Comment: All the comments are great, but this seems to be the best minimalist solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3 then you can make an enum of months [Enum Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

```
from enum import Enum, auto
class Months(Enum):
    JAN = auto()
    FEB = auto()
    ...
```

`auto()` will automatically increment the value for each month so you dont need to worry about bugs that might be caused my incorrect numbering

So you can access them like

```
Months.JAN
```

or

```
Months(1) # returns <Months.JAN: 1>
```

It is a good idea to group constants into Enums as they become the single source of truth for the entire program. Using strings for this purpose can lead to many bugs due to typos.

Storing it in a dict or array is also not advisable as anyone can mutate them in run-time which can be very difficult to debug. Enum values are immutable so they cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dictionary like:

```
names_to_int = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, ...}
```

and then just do:

```
month = names_to_int[month]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Dictionaries here:

```
d={"JANUARY":1,"FEBRUARY":2,"MARCH":3,"APRIL":4,"MAY":5,"JUNE":6,"JULY":7,"AUGUST":8,"SEPTEMBER":9,"OCTOBER":10,"NOVEMBER":11,"DECEMBER":12}

print(d[input()])
```

This gives you direct answer

Answer (score 0):

The code with .index(month) (see the other answer) requires O(n) time every time you want to get an index of a month (maybe O(log n) with some good string indexing under the hood, not sure if that is the case for python). I would suggest using a dictionary of months (then it is O(1) on average, i.e. it runs faster):

```
months = ['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY' ...]
months_map = {month: i for i,month in enumerate(months)}
a_month_idx = months['a month name']
```

Answer (score 0):

`calendar` & `enumerate` to the rescue (use m.upper() if you want)

```
import calendar

m2num = {m: i for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_name)}
print(m2num["January"])
```